# VB.NET - POST request not running properly

Tags: vb.net, web-services, post, cookies, http-post

I'm writing a web service that grabs and returns the HTML for a specific page of our website. The website requires a login so I'm first trying to POST the login info to the login page so I get the cookie I need to be able to access the page I want. Then, I'm trying to grab the page I actually want.

Here's my code:

```
Dim http As HttpWebRequest = TryCast(WebRequest.Create("http://www.mywebsite.com/loginpage"), HttpWebRequest)
http.KeepAlive = True
http.Method = "POST"
http.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
Dim postData As String = "My post data"
Dim dataBytes As Byte() = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData)
http.ContentLength = dataBytes.Length

Using postStream As Stream = http.GetRequestStream()
    postStream.Write(dataBytes, 0, dataBytes.Length)
End Using

Dim httpResponse As HttpWebResponse = TryCast(http.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
http = TryCast(WebRequest.Create("http://www.mywebsite.com/desiredpage"), HttpWebRequest)
http.CookieContainer = New CookieContainer()
http.CookieContainer.Add(httpResponse.Cookies)
Dim httpResponse2 As HttpWebResponse = TryCast(http.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)

Using httpResponse2
    Using reader As New StreamReader(httpResponse2.GetResponseStream())
        Dim html As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
        Return html
    End Using
End Using
```

My problem is this: Instead of successfully logging in and returning the desired cookie, I just receive the HTML for the login page back. This isn't totally surprising since `mywebsite.com/desiredpage` redirects to the login page if the cookie isn't present.

**UPDATE:**
Wireshark is telling me that the website is returning 6 cookies: `.ASPXANONYMOUS`, `language`, `USERNAME_CHANGED`, `authentication`, `.DOTNETNUKE`, and `returnurl`. I've confirmed the first 3 are being stored in `http.CookieContainer` but the other 3 are not.

What is happening to the remaining 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was in the way I was passing the cookies from the first request to the second.

Creating a separate `CookieContainer` and using it in two separate requests fixed the issue:

```
Dim http As HttpWebRequest = TryCast(WebRequest.Create("http://www.mywebsite.com/loginpage"), HttpWebRequest)
http.KeepAlive = True
http.Method = "POST"
http.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
Dim postData As String = "My post data"
Dim dataBytes As Byte() = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData)
http.ContentLength = dataBytes.Length
Dim myCookies As CookieContainer = New CookieContainer()
http.CookieContainer = myCookies

Using postStream As Stream = http.GetRequestStream()
    postStream.Write(dataBytes, 0, dataBytes.Length)
End Using

Dim httpResponse As HttpWebResponse = TryCast(http.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
Dim http2 As HttpWebRequest = TryCast(WebRequest.Create("http://www.mywebsite.com/desiredpage"), HttpWebRequest)
http2.CookieContainer = myCookies
Dim httpResponse2 As HttpWebResponse = TryCast(http2.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)

Using httpResponse2
    Using reader As New StreamReader(httpResponse2.GetResponseStream())
        Dim html As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
        Return html
    End Using
End Using
```